# Squid Proxy not working for HTTP, but works for HTTPS

Tags: python, http, proxy, python-requests, squid

I am testing my forward proxy using squid, where client IP address is `X.X.X.X` and proxy IP address is `Y.Y.Y.Y`.
I have added the following lines to `/etc/squid/squid.conf`

```
acl specialIP src X.X.X.X
http_access allow specialIP
```

To check that the proxy is working, I am requesting these two urls:
https://checkip.amazonaws.com/ 
http://checkip.amazonaws.com/

The proxy works fine for https://checkip.amazonaws.com/ where as expected I receive the response `Y.Y.Y.Y`, the proxy's IP address, and the access log shows:

```
1603269551.021    416 X.X.X.X TCP_TUNNEL/200 5638 CONNECT checkip.amazonaws.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/34.200.69.241 -
```

**However when I request http://checkip.amazonaws.com/, I receive the response `X.X.X.X`, the client IP address, and the access log shows:**

```
1603269592.564    182 X.X.X.X TCP_MISS/200 250 GET http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/34.200.69.241 -
```

**This is incorrect, as I should receive a response of `Y.Y.Y.Y` when using http. Do I need to make changes to the config file?**

Adding the below info, but may not be relevant:
i am using python requests package to make the proxy request. The code i am using for that is as follows:

```
import requests

proxy = {'https': 'Y.Y.Y.Y:3128', 'http': 'Y.Y.Y.Y:3128'}

url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/'

response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: You should use next proxy format: `http://Y.Y.Y.Y:3128`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Do you mean the follow line should read: proxy = {'https': 'Y.Y.Y.Y:3128', 'http': 'http:/ /Y.Y.Y.Y:3128'} ?

Comment: Yes, but set same values for both `https` and `http` keys. You can find example in [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies).

Comment: @OlvinRoght Unfortunately this has not worked, I've used the same key for both https and http, using `http://Y.Y.Y.Y:3128`. I still correctly receive `Y.Y.Y.Y` when using https, but `X.X.X.X` when using http